# Foreach is not working properly php in_array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

You need to display a specific part of the array. Unfortunately, I can't use in_array. Foreach is not working properly. Why does my code only reflect the last elements of an array? How to extract a specific part of an array from an array?

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [$ id] => 1
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [n] => 1
                    [Product] => MH OC52
                    [Item] => MH OC52
                    [Item2] => MH OC52
                    [isPic] => MH OC52
                    [Brand] => MAHLE
                    [Name] => Oil filter
                    [Found By] => MH OC52
                    [For Labels1] =>
                    [Price] => 136.82
                    [Retail] => 231.9
                    [codeDisc] => ES2
                    [Markup] => 0
                    [noReturn] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [n] => 2
                    [Product] => CH C104.12
                    [Item] => CH C104.12
                    [Item2] => .......
                    
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [n] => 2
                    [Product] => WX WL7074-12
                    [Item] => WX WL7074-12
                    ........
```

Here is my code:

```
if (is_array( $obj)) {
foreach($obj['items'] as $key=>$obRes){
 if ($ter = in_array("C104.12", $obRes))  {

    echo  ' tak' ;
} 
else {
    echo  "NOT Good";
}

}

var_dump ($key, $obRes['Price'],$obRes['Item'], $obRes['Bran'], $obRes['Name']);
```

```
1 tak tak tak tak tak tak tak tak tak tak tak takint (12)
float (56.03)
string (13) "WX WL7074-12"
string (5) "WIXFILTRON"
string (29) "Oil filter"

(
)
```

I ask for help

I need to get data:

```
                    [Item] => CH C104.12
                    [Brand] => CHAMPION
                    [Name] => Oil filter           
                    [Price] => 35.69
```

Comment: I'd like to help but I don't understand what you're asking. It sounds like you're trying to get the entire array item [1] based on the value of one of its keys. Is that true?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php `==` compares, `=` assigns

Comment: From the array I want to get only : [Item] => WX WL7074-12
[Brand] => WIXFILTRON
[Name] => Oil filter
[Price] => 56.03

Comment: Brother, simply use == (double equal to) to comparison. if ($ter == in_array("C104.12", $obRes))

Comment: Why does my code issue? The last part of the array?

Comment: if ($ter == in_array("C104.12", $obRes))   Does not work

Comment: Please clarify (by editing your post) exactly what you're trying to retrieve from your array. It's quite unclear right now. You want items where *any* value *contains* "C104.12"?

Comment: I have an API request. From which I get an array of data. From this array only need to be extracted:
                      [Item] => CH C104.12
                     [Brand] => CHAMPION
                     [Name] => Oil filter
                     [Price] => 35.69

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you try to find a value in an array of arrays you can use the `FilterIterator` class of php. Let 's have a look, how this can be done.

We assume, that your inner arrays always have the same keys like in the following example:

```
$data = [
    [
        'product' => 'Product A',
        'brand' => 'Brand A',
        'price' => 12.34,
    ],
    [
        'product' => 'Product B',
        'brand' => 'Brand B',
        'price' => 56.78,
    ],
    [
        'product' => 'Product C',
        'brand' => 'Brand C',
        'price' => 90.12,
    ],
];
```

As you can see this array of arrays is structured like your own array. For example reasons, it is not the same. After all, you should learn how to solve your issue. ;)

So let us have a look, how `FilterIterator` can help you. First we need to specify a filter, which filters your array on a product name.

```
class ProductFilterIterator extends \FilterIterator
{
     protected $filter;

     public function __construct(\Iterator $iterator, string $filter)
     {
         $this->filter = $filter;
         parent::__construct($iterator);
     }

     public function accept() : bool
     {
         $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
         return $current['product'] == $this->filter;
     }
}
```

This is a pretty simple `FilterIterator` class, that takes a given filter and compares it with the product key of one of your inner arrays of your collection of arrays. The `accept` method of the filter iterator returns true, when the given product 'Product B' is found in the array. Otherwise it returns false. Let 's search for a product with the name 'Product B' in a short example.

```
$iterator = (new \ArrayObject($data))->getIterator();
$filter = new ProductFilterIterator($iterator, 'Product B');

foreach ($filter as $data) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

The result of this filtered iteration is:

```
array(3) {
    ["product"] => string(9) "Product B"
    ["brand"] => string(7) "Brand B"
    ["price"] => float(56.78)
}
```

I guess this would be the best practice solution nowadays for filtering multidimensional arrays like yours. Encapsulated iteration like you 've tried on your own can work, but looks the most of the time very odd and hard to refactor. Checking values in a foreach in a foreach loop was done in the past. You should apply more up-to-date php techniques. It 's 2019. ;)

Comment: Substitute your data and get it : Warning: Illegal string offset 'items' in......

Comment: Well ... I don 't know what you did. But you did something wrong. Try again.

Comment: $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
         return $current['Product'] == $this->filter;
     }
}

$iterator = (new \ArrayObject($obj))->getIterator();
$filter = new ProductFilterIterator($iterator, 'CH C104.12');

foreach ($filter as $obj) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($obj);

Comment: Just try `$iterator = (new \ArrayObject($obj['items']))->getIterator();`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How to implement this code when, CH C104.12 = C104.12. The search is performed from the database of C104.12. And the site adds from the front of CH the first letters [Brand] => CH .....

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will be a beginner and I know little

Comment: I'm getting an error- Fatal error: Cannot declare class ProductFilterIterator, because the name is already in use in